# why second time button click not work properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

i am making a row on button click.First time it work fine please expand and check .but hen i click second time it not make same as first.
http://jsfiddle.net/R2DzV/5/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.btn_handler').click(function(){
 $("#list").append('<li><div data-role="collapsible"><h3>name</h3><ul><li><div fieldset data-role="controlgroup" id="Smoker"><input type="radio" name="radio-choice" id="radio-choice-1" value="TestCase" checked="checked"><label for="radio-choice-1">Add Test Case</label><input type="radio" name="radio-choice" id="radio-choice-2" value="TestCommand"><label for="radio-choice-2">Add Test Command</label></fieldset>' + '<a  data-role="button" data-mini="true" data-theme="a">Add</a></div></li></ul></div></li>');   
        $('#list').trigger('create');
        $('#list').listview('refresh');

    })

});
```

Comment: Which browser you are using? for me its working on FF and chrom

Comment: You are probably using `id` instead of `class` in your HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this in your `.append()`:

```
<div fieldset data-role="controlgroup" id="Smoker">
```

with:

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" id="Smoker">
```

And then fix the obvious problem that you should only have unique ID's (you can maybe make them classes instead).

Comment: You have also deleted the `checked` which you should not. See this Fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/R2DzV/8/

Comment: can we give different Its' so that I can get click event ..or add ID on header tag instead of name  "test case_1" "testcase_2"

Answer (score 0):

Your code has duplicate IDs being generated.

Remove the `id="Smoker"` and learn something new:

```
<label><input type="radio" /> Click the text and the radio button gets it!</label>
```

Comment: @Kiranramchandran That's why I am teaching about using `<label>` *around* the radio button, without a `for/id` combo.

Comment: @user2484319 Because, for reasons only you know, you removed the `name` attribute from the radio buttons. Without it, you can't check it!

Comment: can we add different ids on each row (pace it on header tag as display).

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol can you give bette solution.

Comment: You accepted someone else's answer. That means your problem is solved. Bye!

Comment: can we give different Its' so that I can get click event ..or add ID on header tag instead of name  "test case_1" "testcase_2"

Comment: Yes. Just have a counter that increases each time you call the function. By the way, accepting *my* answer still means your problem has been solved.